# how to get position or index of element in spinner

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a spinner in my code and I want to get position of element in the array when selected. Here is my code which is running perfectly. In selection I am storing the string value of  element but I also want the position count of element

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;
    private String selection;
    private String[] states  = new String[]{
            "Gujrat","Jammu and Kashmir","Kerala","Karnataka","Lakshadweep","Maharashtra","Manipur","Mizoram",
            "Nagaland","New Delhi","Rajasthan","Tami Nadu","West Bengal"
    };
    ArrayList<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

        //make it fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //fix portrait orientation
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menu);
                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncross);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
                Spinner spin = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinState);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
                adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter_state);

                spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });



    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv = (TextView)arg1;
        selection = tv.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + selection);

    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: In your onItemSelected method the arg2 is the index in the array. Consider renaming parameters, i.e. arg0 -> pAdapter, arg1 -> pV, arg2 -> pPosition, arg3 -> pId. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arg2 of `onItemSelected()` is the position of selected items.
```

So you can use it like

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                           long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    selection = states[arg2];
    Log.v(TAG, "index=" + arg2);
    Log.v(TAG, "selction=" + selection);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                           long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv = (TextView)arg1;
    selection = tv.getText().toString();
    Log.v(TAG, "index=" + selection);

}
```

**arg2** is the position of spinner

Answer (score 1):

Here in your `setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()`

```
public abstract void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

**Parameters**

1. **parent**  The AdapterView where the selection happened
2. **view**    The view within the AdapterView that was clicked
3. **position**    The position of the view in the adapter
4. **id**  The row id of the item that is selected

Answer (score 1):

```
spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

**`int arg2`** to get **Selected Item Id**

Update only this method,

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v(TAG, "index=" + spin.getItemIdAtPosition(int2));
}
```